# NumbaPerformanceWarning occured when using pandas.Series.rolling.apply() for custom function

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, group-by, numba

I want to use numba.jit to accelerate the execution of `pandas.Series.rolling.apply()`. However, I met `NumbaPerformanceWarning` when run this:

```
from itertools import product
import datetime as dt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numba
date = [
    dt.date(2019,1,1),
    dt.date(2019,1,2),
    dt.date(2019,1,3),
    dt.date(2019,1,4)
]
people = [1,2,3,4,5]
idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([date, people], names = ['date','people'])
data = pd.Series(np.random.random(20), index=idx)
```

```py
def ts_ewm(s, window):
    def ewm(s):
        half_life = 63
        weight = 0.5**(np.arange(s.size-1,-1,-1)/half_life)
        return np.sum(s * weight)/np.sum(weight)
    res = s.groupby('people').rolling(window, min_periods=window//2)
    res = res.apply(ewm, raw=True, engine="numba", engine_kwargs={"parallel": True})
    res = res.droplevel(0)
    res = res.reindex_like(s)
    return res
```

```py
ts_ewm(data, 3)
```

I got:

```
/jupyterhub/miniconda3/envs/jupyterhub/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/window/numba_.py:70: NumbaPerformanceWarning: 
The keyword argument 'parallel=True' was specified but no transformation for parallel execution was possible.

To find out why, try turning on parallel diagnostics, see https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/parallel.html#diagnostics for help.

File "../../../../jupyterhub/miniconda3/envs/jupyterhub/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/util/numba_.py", line 107:

            def impl(data, *_args):
            ^

  result[i] = numba_func(window, *args)
```

In the `ewm()` function, all of the operations ar numpy functions. I have checked the document from numba and pandas, but found nothing. May anyone save me from this bug? And I would be really appreciate if anyone could tell me the correct way to use custom functions for rolling apply with numba. Thank you so much!

I want the program to run automatically in parallel with numba in pandas.Series.rolling.apply.

Comment: It's not a bug. It just means that Numba can't parallelize anything within a single function call, so setting it to True doesn't add anything (hence the warning). That's totally fine and valid. It doesn't mean that Pandas won't call the function in parallel on different windows at the same time (I don't know if it will).

Comment: Btw, the latest Numba release (0.57.1) can actually parallelize (parts of) a single function call.

Comment: Yes, it is a warning not an error. But I think it means that the function does not execute in parallel (the speed is also slow). Thus, I wonder if there's a method to modify this function to parallel.  Thank you.